# Crosshair following the mouse position along the Y axis of the player in a top down 2d game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm programming a 2d top down game with Unity about starships. Actually the starship stay in the center of the screen (**0x.0y**). The starships rotate along his axis with a delay until she reaches the mouse position with his y axis.
I want to do a crosshair that stay in the y axis of the ship and follow its rotation to represent where the ship is exactly pointing doing delayed rotation. The crosshair have to always reach the center of the mouse cursor when the ship is aligned with the mouse. This crosshair is a Transform variable called "aim".
Any help would be appreciated.
This is what i tried:
'''C#

```
public Transform aim;//AIM position "aim image"
public float aimSpeed;//speed AIM
public float zonaMorta;//death zone value where the AIM can't move

private Vector3 target;//position where the AIM need to go
private Vector3 posAim;//AIM position

void Update ()
    {
        float pr = transform.rotation.z;//take the rotation value from the player
        float ty = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y;//y axis value of the mouse.
        target = new Vector3(0 , ty, 0);//allowance the y axis of the cursor to "target"
        posAim = aim.transform.position;//allowance AIM position to "posAim"
        posAim = new Vector3(0, posAim.y, 0);//on posAim I keep only y while x, z gate them

        if(posAim.y + zonaMorta > target.y && posAim.y - zonaMorta < target.y)//if AIM is between this two value then it can't move, it can't move in the y axis
    {

    }else{

        if(pr > -90f || pr < 90f){//if the rotation of the player is more than -90 degrees or less than 90 degrees then ..
            if(posAim.y > target.y)//if y axis of AIM is greater than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                aim.transform.position -= aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//subtract and allowance at the AIM position a positive velocity in the y axis
            }
            if(posAim.y < target.y)//if y axis of AIM is lesser than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                    aim.transform.position += aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//sum and allowance at the AIM position a positive velocity in the y axis
                }                   
                }
      if(pr < -90f || pr > 90f){//if the rotation of the player is less than -90 degrees or more than 90 degrees then ..

            if(posAim.y > target.y)//if y axis of AIM is greater than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                aim.transform.position -= -aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//subtract and allowance at the AIM position a negative velocity in the y axis
            }
            if(posAim.y < target.y)//if y axis of AIM is lesser than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                    aim.transform.position += -aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//sum and allowance at the AIM position a negative velocity in the y axis
                }                   
                }
            }
        }
```

'''

In this case i created a dead zone but this method don't work As excepted: the crosshair, when the ship is moving, will always go up and down along y axis. I read about Vector3.Lerp but i actually dont know how to use It.

Comment: Could you add the code of what you tried so far please?

Comment: Once you've supplied some code as asked by @derHugo, it sounds like you may want to use Lerp: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: Can't you simply parent your "crosshair" to your ship, so it will rotate with it ? Or did I understand something wrong ?

Comment: Added code.  Pls can u explain me a working code with Vector3.Lerp? I actually dont know how to use it

Comment: The crosshair would be parented with ship but the crosshair 
have to rotate and move on the y axis to reach mouse position too. I dont want a fixed crosshair rotating only